# How to save the contents of Data URI to image

Tags: javascript

In Google Chrome the method `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(integer windowId, object options, function callback)` ([captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)) will return a data URL of the JPEG encoding of the visible area of the captured tab.

We want to save that content as image to hard disk without opening/passing the contents into new HTML page.

Does anybody know how it can be done by JavaScript.
Please provide help.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out one of the extensions that do this, e.g.: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
Yes we gone through this extension, but this also passes the data URI contents as 'src' to <img> and displays it in new web page & asks us to right click on the image & save it. But we want to directly save the contents to image.